# Cross tenant updates of Databases on tables separated by companyID

Tags: acumatica

I have a table that has a CompanyID column.

Lets say I have the following 2 records

```
CompanyID    KeyValue    Descr
2            00000001    This is the record in tenant 2
3            00000005    This is the record in tenant 3
```

Can I use something like PXDatabase.Update to update the CompanyID = 3 record (change the description to "This was updated from tenant 2") from some process running in the context of tenant 2?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: Most likely the only way would be to create some stored procedure and then invoke it from code. I don't think there is a way to affect the company id from C# side

Comment: Wrote a small integration to get tracking number updates thru webhooks, client has 6 tenants, dont want to have 6 shipengine accounts pointing to each tenants webhook url, tracking number is a unique key, want to be able to call a webhook on a single tenant and update the tracking info for any shipment on the entire acumatica instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't because all the database operations you do will be constrained to the current tenant by BQL. If you want to update something in another tenant, you have to initialize a PXLoginScope.

Comment: Got it, I guess I will just have to make a cross tenant sql view. Thanks.

Comment: And there is no way to do this using something lower level like PXDatabase.Update ?